# Copy files from server using DRAC

Tags: windows, drac

Is it possible to copy files from a server that runs windows through the iDRAC interface?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you *can* do is create an `iso` file with the file that you would like to transfer, and then mount the `ISO`using iDRAC. This is however a one-way-street.

Comment: What I want to do is to transfer files from the server and not to the server.

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't think this is possible

Comment: You could mount a virtual _floppy_ disk, but 1.44Mo is probably not enough space to transfer anything useful.

Comment: (iwork4dell) I believe you can attach a USB key.  If your iDRAC has vflash you can use that as well.